# Upload files to Ionic?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, facebook-opengraph

I am new to ionic, and a little lost; my former colleague was working on a mobile app, using this framework, but right now, he isn't in the company, so I have the responsibility to develop the app.

I already installed Cordova and node.js and I was able to download the app, via command window, to make some modifications, but I don't know how to upload the changes to Ionic Creator; the only thing that I was able to find was how to run the server and to emulate android and iOS.

You may ask, why would I want to download, make modifications and upload the changes? Right now, there is a button which is supposed to log in to Facebook, and extract some information. I already have the javascript code to do that, but I want to add it to the app itself, and have it running, but I am lost here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation here:
 http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/uploading_viewing.html

Use `ionic upload`command to upload to ionic view app.

I hope this helps.